# Dynamically selecting a table row in an application with Power Automate Desktop

Tags: power-automate, uielement, power-automate-desktop

I'm working on a Power Automate Desktop flow to automate some actions... at one stage there is a datatable in a winforms-esque application which i need to double click on a row within.

This needs to by dynamic, based on the data in one of the cells in said row.

I can't share the exact data, so i've made a little mock up...

[image]

For the purposes of example, lets say i've already determined that the "id" of the row i need to select is '1002'... I've added this to a variable.

[image]

I'm struggling to find non-web based documentation or examples online, and the few that I have found seem to have a completely different layout than the current Power Automate Desktop, so i've had no success so far moving from a static selection to a dynamic one.

I understand I need to dynamically select a UI element, but I'm really struggling with the syntax to do that - everything i've thrown at it so far has failed.

The most recent attempt was

```
 > pane[Id="Panel1"] > table[Id="DataGridView1"] > text:eq(%SelectionID%)
```

but that fails to locate and select any elements for me to continue.

I feel like this should be really simple, and yet having spent hours trying different techniques and syntax I'm making zero progress.

Is anyone able to shove me in the right direction please?

[image]

Comment: a bit of a wild guess, but should that variable not be wrapped in text quotes?  `> pane[Id="Panel1"] > table[Id="DataGridView1"] > text:eq("%SelectionID%")`

Comment: Can you add your mockup app code as when I try and mock up an app the selector end up being different. ` > datagrid[Id="dataGridView1"] > custom[Name="Row 1"] > dataitem[Id="4239974954"] `